Using Custom FontAwesome Icons in Highcharts
I have a web application that uses Highcharts. I have been able to use FontAwesome 5 icons as markers/icons in my charts, by doing the following:
    series: {
        cursor: 'default',
        marker: {
            symbol: "textn:\uf183", // fa-male
            radius: 10,
        },

This works fine. Where I am running into an issue is trying to use custom icons. I have a Pro account and am allowed to import SVGs to create custom FA icons. I have done so, but when I try to use the unicode, instead of the image I see the string literal text. For example, the following unicode correlates to my custom version of the male icon in my FA kit:
series: {
    cursor: 'default',
    marker: {
        symbol: "textn:\e002", // fa-male
        radius: 10,
    },

Instead of seeing my little dude, though, I just see "e002".
I have verified that the FA source I am using is my kit that contains the custom icons. I have also verified the unicode of the icon (copied it directly from FA).
Any idea on what I am missing here? Are custom icons just not directly accessible via Unicode like native FA icons are?

Maybe the problem lies in the order, e.g. you initialize the chart before creating custom FA icons?
